# Result set not working in OLE DB connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am creating a SSIS Package to retrieve the max date for a table. I created a OLE DB connection and could not get it to return a value. I tried Result Name 0 and MaxDate the name of the variable returned. I changed the connection type to ADO and if the query returned a Date type it works but with a convert to string it doesn't. I really only need '03/06/2018'. Can some one explain why I can return a string in either and only a date in ADO?

My two queries are:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25), MAX(MailDate), 120) AS MaxDate
FROM dbo.FULF_Cycle_Table

SELECT MAX(MailDate)
FROM dbo.FULF_Cycle_Table
```

Here is my SQL Task

[image]

Comment: I deleted the Execute SQL task and recreated it and the OLE DB now works. It returns a string even though I use the unformatted query but it works. So good enough.

Comment: So you fixed this then and there is no question now?